# How to make rainbow csv in vscode ignore some separators?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some data items that look like `["A","B"]` but rainbow csv extension is color coding the `["A",` and `"B"]` differently because of the comma. How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks

edit: and there are other data points beside each other that look like `"C","D"` with the `","` pattern

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a CSV that uses coma (*,*) as separator of columns, you could quote them like *"[A,B]", "[C,D]"*
or
*"['A','B']", "['C','D']"*

If the file is a `CSV` that uses semicolon (*;*) as separator of columns, try forcing Visual Studio Code to use semicolon as separator by clicking *`CSV`* at the bottom-right corner and selecting *`CSV` (semicolon)*.

Answer (score 0):

In the parameters of the application you have choice to add or delete some separator (if I understand the problem correctly)